# Expo-doctor --fix-dependencies not working deprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, dependencies, package.json

Expo doctor FIX dependencies not working

```
npx expo-doctor --fix-dependencies
(node:11556) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

I dont know why I am getting this because in my package.json file I got the puny code version

```
"punycode": "^2.3.1",
```

Comment: any thoughts???